# Two chips drawn from urn, calculate $P(|\hat\theta - 3| > 1.0)$.

Tags: probability, estimation

Two chips are drawn without replacements from an urn containing 5 chips, numbered 1-5. The average of the two drawn is to be used as an estimator, $\hat\theta$, for the true average of all the chips ($\theta$). Calculate $P(|\hat\theta - 3| > 1.0)$.

solution:  $P(|\hat\theta - 3| > 1.0) = P(\hat\theta < 2) + P(\hat\theta > 4) = P(\hat\theta = 1.5) + P(\hat\theta = 4.5) = P(1,2) + P(4.5) = \frac{2}{10}$.

I don't understand why the average is between $1.5$ and $4.5$

can someone please help me understand this problem? I understand until $P(|\hat\theta - 3| > 1.0) = P(\hat\theta < 2) + P(\hat\theta > 4) $
The answer is 2/10.

i would appreciate. Thanks

Comment: What does the statement "used as an estimator, θ^, for the true average of all the chips (θ)" has anything to do with the question at hand? BTW, the true average of all the chips is simply $3$, why make things complicated?

Comment: how would that help? I have the solution in the book, yet don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I don't understand why the average is between 1.5 and 4.5`:

- The smallest two values that you can choose are $1$ and $2$, with an average of $1.5$.
- The largest  two values that you can choose are $4$ and $5$, with an average of $4.5$.

---

**As to the question itself:**

Let $X$ denote the average of the selected numbers

Then $P(|X-3|>1)=P([X<2]\vee[X>4])$

There are $\color{red}{10}$ ways to choose $2$ out of $5$ numbers:

- $1,2\implies{X=1.5<2}$
- $1,3\implies{X=2.0}$
- $1,4\implies{X=2.5}$
- $1,5\implies{X=3.0}$
- $2,3\implies{X=2.5}$
- $2,4\implies{X=3.0}$
- $2,5\implies{X=3.5}$
- $3,4\implies{X=3.5}$
- $3,5\implies{X=4.0}$
- $4,5\implies{X=4.5>4}$

As you can see, there are $\color{red}{2}$ cases where $[X<2]$ or $[X>4]$, hence the probability is $\color{red}{\dfrac{2}{10}}$.

Comment: thanks for making it clear.

Comment: @user4802: You're welcome :)